# How to get 0.9 instead of 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, math.h

I am having a simple problem i want to get value after decimal points,Here is my code,

`float result  = slotSize/60;//slot size is int and 57`

I want result 0.95 ,but i am getting 0,please help me.I tried ceil value method but it gives 1 and floor value method gives 0.

Comment: Instead of `60`, try `60.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your slotSize type from Int to Float.

Comment: While this is one option, it is not required. Simply change 60 to 60.0 and leave slotSize an int.